# Saving generated pdf in the database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, pdf

I'm working on asp.net application where it takes input from user in multiple form and save in pdf. Now I'm stuck where I don't know how to save the generated pdf in the SQL Server database.

With this, I'm attaching code for saving in pdf.

```
protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Samba.pdf");
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

   StringWriter st = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(st);

   gvExperience.AllowPaging = false;
   gvExperience.DataBind();
   gvExperience.RenderControl(ht);

   StringReader sr1 = new StringReader(st.ToString());
   Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);

   HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
   PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
   pdfDoc.Open();
   htmlparser.Parse(sr1);
   pdfDoc.Close();

   Response.Write(pdfDoc);
   Response.End();  
}
```

Comment: You probably want to save the .pdf to the filesystem and save a string path pointing to the resource in the database. What have you tried?

Comment: Or..use Google and find this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/311148/Save-and-view-pdf-file-from-SQL-server-database-in

Comment: Don't assume we know what database you are using. Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, or something else?

Whatever the database, you have two options. Save it on your filesystem and just save the path to the database. Or save it as a BLOB.

Comment: @DGibbs,I'm trying to generate the pdf and save straight to the database without saving to local disk. For now, I have just managed to generate the pdf and save it to local disk.

Comment: @Andrew,I have came across this solution but I still stuck with since I'm planning to generate the pdf and save straight to the database without saving on local disk.

Comment: @msm8bball,sorry mate.my mistake. I'm using SQL Server. I'm planning to generate the pdf and save straight to the database without saving on local disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a table with at least the name of the file (varchar(100), the content (varbinary(max)), and the length of the content (int).

Convert pdf to byte array (byte[]).  I would swap our your Reponse.OutputStream for a memory stream.  Save to Sql Server with your prefered data access method.

Sql server's 'varbinary' will translate to C#'s 'byte[]'.  When you're writing it back to the client's browser you'll want to set the 'content-type' header and write to the stream with 'Response.BinaryWrite(byte[])'.

Comment: Is it possible to help me with coding for the mentioned part as I'm totally new to this.

Comment: I can't give you code, however you'll require System.IO.MemoryStream.  Something like 'var stream = new MemoryStream(); {write to stream} var bytes = stream.ToArray();'.  As for your data access, I would just implement an Entity Framework context for simplicity.  After creating your database and schema, Entity Framework provides mechanisms for auto-importing and mapping your schema to code.

Comment: Thanks, finally understood what you mentioned above.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Convert to base64 string then insert into DB.

```
byte[] pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);
```

Happy coding. :)